# Error when executing R kernel in Jupyter with nbclient package (Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:1: unexpected input)

Tags: python, r, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

Using the nbclient package to remotely execute an R kernel, the package works fine with the python kernels (3.7/3.9) however gives this error when attempting the run an R kernel.

The following is the error :-

````
  File "/code/proj/spawner/execution_backend/bivalve.py", line 160, in _execute
    self._results = self._notebook_client.execute(reset_kc=True, env=env)
  File "/build/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 75, in wrapped
    return just_run(coro(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/build/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 54, in just_run
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/build/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 564, in async_execute
    cell, index, execution_count=self.code_cells_executed + 1
  File "/build/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 839, in async_execute_cell
    self._check_raise_for_error(cell, cell_index, exec_reply)
  File "/build/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 755, in _check_raise_for_error
    raise CellExecutionError.from_cell_and_msg(cell, exec_reply['content'])
nbclient.exceptions.CellExecutionError: An error occurred while executing the following cell:
------------------
__nbparams__ = {"__meta__": {"lookup_service": {"data": "{\"timestamp\": \"2022-09-30T14:46:18.491258\", \"user\": \"vkamat\", \"notebook\": 2431}", "signature": "630e510e60a286a17881fc513e54e54c"}}}
globals().update(__nbparams__)
------------------

Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:1: unexpected input
1: _
    ^
Traceback:

ERROR: Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:1: unexpected input
1: _
```    ^
````

Comment: the R kernel is for R code, but you are submitting python ?

Comment: Yeah, the R kernel starts-up fine and executes when running from the Jupyter portal. I ripped the kernel-launcher from here which works fine.

Its the remote-execution from the nbclient package that throws the error.

Comment: Link to kernel-launcher : https://github.com/jupyter-server/enterprise_gateway/tree/main/etc/kernel-launchers/R/scripts

Comment: The kernel wasn't in the list of valid kernels, I created a custom name for the R kernel which was not getting processed.